# Move message From one Queue to other Queue without deleting it Rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I have the following problem.

My program sends messages directly to the Queue (without exchange). I need to monitor incoming of new messages and send them to other Queue without removing them from source queue.

I don't have access to program code, so I'm not able to publish messages to exchange first.

Is it possible to solve this problem using the management web interface of RabbitMQ?

I tried to use shovel plugin, but it removes all messages from source queue after ack.

Answer (score 2):

First to clear up few things:

`My program sends messages directly to the Queue (without exchange)` **This is not true**, at the very least (and most likely in this case) nameless exchange is used.

`removes all messages from source queue after ack`
this is by design and therefore perfectly fine.

You should never keep messages in the queue, **queue is made to be consumed**. As Derick Bailey says [here](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/21/how-to-do-user-notifications-from-rabbitmq-messages/)

> RabbitMQ is not a database. RabbitMQ is a message broker and queueing system.

on the same link you will find your answer. I cannot give a concrete one since you didn't provide motivation, but whatever it is keeping messages in the queue is never good!

Maybe you want to log/store your message first and then process it with the consequence of processing being some 3rd action or whatever...

Comment: here is a tag attempt for @derick-bailey - since being mentioned :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was wrong. 
I have the following situation. Program publish messages to some Queue using default direct exchange (routing key is Queue name).
Are there any way to monitor new messages incoming to the source Queue, and send them to destination Queue, without removing them from source as I mentioned before?
PS: source queue also has consumers that pulls messages from it.

Comment: @seriks, hey no problem, that's why SO and everyone on it are here ;)

Comment: Sure. You could use the web UI or rabbitmqctrl, but I'm not sure if that you can actually see the payload of the message without retrieving it. Maybe there is some 3rd party plugin, or something that I don't know that enables you to do this... As I mentioned in the answer, you could write another subscriber that intercepts, store and forwards the message..

Comment: thank you. 
Yeah, I think plugin that could consume messages from queue without retrieving them from it, is my solution, but I have never seen something similar to it